# Is it possible to somehow overcome type erasure in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, wicket, type-erasure

Here's the thing.
We use a lot of Wicket Panels in our application, and for testing purposes they should ideally be generated generically. Part of this works, in theory: For every parameter type in a constructor I have only one possible argument to offer, so it is a matter of finding what these parameter types are - Reflection.
Problem being: Type Erasure. Many of the constructors use multiple versions of the Model< > class as parameters with various different type parameters to it. Type Erasure means that as far as I can find I have no way to differentiate between these at runtime.
So, in this situation, is there any way to overcome or circumvent type erasure?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?  Type erasure is a part of the Java language specification, so there is no way to "turn it off," but there could be a workaround for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem long before you use reflection and if you fix this, you not longer need to worry.

As there is no way to tell the difference between `Model<A>` and `Model<B>` you cannot overload two methods or constructors with these types.  Instead you need to create one method which takes a `Model<C>` where C is the super class/interface of A and B.

You can't do this

```
interface A extends C { }
interface B extends C { }

class MyClass {
    MyClass<Model<A> modelA) { }
    MyClass<Model<B> modelB) { }
```

This won't compile as they have the same signature after erasure so instead you can do

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass<Model<? extends C> model) { }
```

Not only does this compile but there is no ambiguity at runtime.